# AWS RDS Proxy unavailalbe - how to debug?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I have created an RDS Proxy using Terraform. However, it does not seem to be working.

My application code cannot connect to the proxy (timeout) and `aws rds describe-db-proxy-targets` gives the following:

```json
{
    "Targets": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "mydb.aaaaaaaaaaaa.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "RdsResourceId": "mydb",
            "Port": 5432,
            "Type": "RDS_INSTANCE",
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "UNAVAILABLE",
                "Description": "DBProxy Target unavailable due to an internal error"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I go about debugging this?

Here is the Terraform script for the proxy. The RDS instance is described elsewhere, but is working.

```
data "aws_subnet" "mydb_rds" {
  filter {
    name   = "availability-zone"
    values = [ aws_db_instance.mydb.availability_zone ]
  }
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "mydb_rds_proxy" {
  name = "mydb-rds-proxy"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "mydb_rds_proxy" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.mydb_rds_proxy.id
  secret_string = var.db_password
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "mydb_rds_proxy" {
  name = "mydb-rds-proxy"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "mydb_rds_proxy_policy" {
  name = "mydb-rds-proxy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GetSecretValue",
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.mydb_rds_proxy.arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DecryptSecretValue",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.mydb_rds_proxy.arn}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "mydb_rds_proxy_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.mydb_rds_proxy.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.mydb_rds_proxy_policy.arn
}

resource "aws_db_proxy" "mydb" {
  name                   = "mydb-rds-proxy"
  debug_logging          = false
  engine_family          = "POSTGRESQL"
  idle_client_timeout    = 1800
  require_tls            = true
  role_arn               = aws_iam_role.mydb_rds_proxy.arn
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.mydb_rds.id ]
  vpc_subnet_ids         = [
    data.aws_subnet.mydb_rds.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_a.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_b.id
  ]

  auth {
    auth_scheme = "SECRETS"
    iam_auth    = "DISABLED"
    secret_arn  = aws_secretsmanager_secret.mydb_rds_proxy.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_db_proxy_default_target_group" "mydb" {
  db_proxy_name = aws_db_proxy.mydb.name

  connection_pool_config {
    connection_borrow_timeout    = 120
    max_connections_percent      = 100
    max_idle_connections_percent = 50
  }
}

resource "aws_db_proxy_target" "mydb" {
  db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.mydb.id
  db_proxy_name          = aws_db_proxy.mydb.name
  target_group_name      = aws_db_proxy_default_target_group.mydb.name
}

locals {
  proxied_pg_connection_string = "postgres://${aws_db_instance.mydb.username}:${var.db_password}@${aws_db_proxy.mydb.endpoint}:5432/postgres?client_encoding=UTF8"
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61278414/aws-rds-proxy-throws-timeout-error-from-nodejs12-x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things you need to get right for this to work:

- Username / password stored in the secret
- Security group rules from Lambda -> RDS Proxy
- Security group rules from RDS Proxy -> RDS
- RDS Proxy, Lambda and RDS in the same VPC
- RDS Proxy role can access the secret

A useful debugging query is:

```sh
aws rds describe-db-proxy-targets --db-proxy-name <proxy-name>
```

To understand the error message it gives back, see [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy.troubleshooting).

The username / password is the hardest thing to discover, since Terraform does not support it yet. What you need to do is construct a JSON string in Terraform that matches what RDS Proxy can understand:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "my_db_proxy" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_db_proxy.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    "username"             = aws_db_instance.my_db.username
    "password"             = var.db_password
    "engine"               = "postgres"
    "host"                 = aws_db_instance.my_db.address
    "port"                 = 5432
    "dbInstanceIdentifier" = aws_db_instance.my_db.id
  })
}
```

You then need ensure these security group rules allowing TCP traffic on port `5432` (for Postgres) exist:

- `ingress` Lambda to RDS Proxy
- `ingress` RDS Proxy to RDS
- `egress` RDS Proxy to `"0.0.0.0/0"`

The RDS Proxy role should have a policy like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_rds_proxy_policy" {
  name = "my-rds-proxy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Action": [
        "rds:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_db_instance.my_db.arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "GetSecretValue",
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.my_rds_proxy.arn}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DecryptSecretValue",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DecryptKms",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Using `describe-db-proxy-targets` is very helpful and can give you the answer you need in some cases. I was getting "DBProxy Target unavailable due to an internal error" as described in the question. Very frustrating! In my case it was caused by having an incorrect security group setup that caused the endpoint to not have access to the target. In my testing I thought using the same security group on the proxy as the RDS cluster made sense, only I forgot that group didn't allow access from its own group. Hopefully AWS can catch this error in the future and improve the error messaging.